# How did I unlock Roselina in Mario Kart Wii?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

I have unlocked Roselina a long time ago and I don't remember how. She is the only character I have ever unlocked. I don't have any Mario Galaxy save, and I don't have the mirror levels, I don't even have all of the cups. I also have no stars for anything. How did I unlock her? Does anyone know?

Comment: Wild guess: second-hand console can still have old saves in memory. Settings -> System memory -> Saves or something along that line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to http://mariokart.wikia.com/wiki/Rosalina

> There are three ways to unlock Rosalina in Mario Kart Wii.
>
> 1. Make a save file on Super Mario Galaxy, then perform 50 races.
> 2. Get a minimum 1 Star ranking on all Cups in 150cc Mirror Mode.
> 3. Play 4950 races.

Since you neither have a Super Mario Galaxy save file nor unlocked Mirror Mode, it seems you just played Mario Kart Wii a lot.

Comment: All races? Multiplayer (local and online) included?

Comment: I can garuntee you I haven't even done 1,000 races on that game. Maybe it's just a glitch?? But thank you.